# A valid Root CA Certificate could not be located, the certificate will likely display browser warnings

Tags: windows, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

i'm trying to get Telegram Webhook working with my local machine but it doesn't make requests. I think it's bc of certificate issue

Here's what geocerts.com/ssl-checker says:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/225CG.png)

Here's my Apache config:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
<VirtualHost *:%httpsport%>

    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%" %aliases%
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"

    SSLEngine       on
    #Header always set          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=94608000"

    SSLCACertificateFile       "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/xxx/xxx-rootCA.crt"
    SSLCertificateChainFile    "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/xxx/xxx-bundle.crt"

    SSLCertificateFile          "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/xxx/xxx-server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile       "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/xxx/xxx-server.key"

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE [1-5].*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE [6-9].*" \
    ssl-unclean-shutdown

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions              +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/">
        SSLOptions              +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I've generated these certificates with a following script:

```
: Version 1.0
: Author unknown (improved by Kama - wp-kama.ru)
@echo off

: parameters
set DOM=xxx.info
set DOM_KEY=xxx
set APACHE_VER=Apache-PHP-7.2-x64

: create .txt config file
set config_txt=generate-temp-config.txt
(
    echo nsComment = "Open Server Panel Generated Certificate"
    echo basicConstraints = CA:false
    echo subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
    echo authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
    echo keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
    echo.
    echo subjectAltName = @alt_names
    echo [alt_names]
    echo DNS.1 = %DOM%
    echo DNS.2 = www.%DOM%
) > %config_txt%

mkdir %DOM_KEY%

set OSAPACHE_DIR=%~dp0..\..\..\modules\http\%APACHE_VER%
set OPENSSL_CONF=%OSAPACHE_DIR%\conf\openssl.cnf
"%OSAPACHE_DIR%\bin\openssl" req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 5475 -keyout %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-rootCA.key -out %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-rootCA.crt -subj /CN=OSPanel-%DOM_KEY%/
"%OSAPACHE_DIR%\bin\openssl" req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 5475 -keyout %DOM_KEY%/%DOM_KEY%-server.key -out %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-server.csr -subj /CN=%DOM_KEY%/
"%OSAPACHE_DIR%\bin\openssl" x509 -req -sha256 -days 5475 -in %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-server.csr -extfile %config_txt% -CA %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-rootCA.crt -CAkey %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-server.crt
"%OSAPACHE_DIR%\bin\openssl" dhparam -out %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-dhparam.pem 2048

del %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-server.csr
del %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-dhparam.pem
del %DOM_KEY%\%DOM_KEY%-rootCA.srl
del %config_txt%

pause
```

I'm not very familiar with certificates and I don't have a lot of time for this rn so I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating the certificates yourself, of course nobody else is going to trust them; that's the whole point of certificates.

You should get a certificate from a public Certification Authority (or use a free solution like Let's Encrypt).

Comment: I see, thanks, I figured it out. Let's Encrypt works